# How to add a pipe after tshark function tshark pipe

Tags: awk, sed, pipe, tshark

I want to use `tshark` to find the destination or source ip that is not mine. For this, I use (`ip-ifconfig` gives my ip from `ifconfig`)

```
# tshark -T fields -e ip.addr -E aggregator=" " | sed "s/$(ip-ifconfig)//"
tshark: Lua: Error during loading:
 [string "/usr/share/wireshark/init.lua"]:44: dofile has been disabled due to running Wireshark as superuser. See https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges for help in running Wireshark as an unprivileged user.
Capturing on 'wlp3s0'
**5500**
```

I get the number of caught packets. I want the IPs instead.

The output may have to be manipulated with `awk`.

The output of this command without the pipe with `sed` is a list of IPs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `sed "s/$(ip-ifconfig)//"` just replaces your IP address with the empty string. This is probably not what you want. Also, I don't know the ip-ifconfig command, I assume it gives you a single IP address.

A crude way to achieve this would be to suppress all lines that contain your IP address, e.g. one of the following two examples:

```
tshark -T fields -e ip.addr -E aggregator=" " | grep -v "$(ip-ifconfig)"
tshark -T fields -e ip.addr -E aggregator=" " | sed "/$(ip-ifconfig)/d"
```

This solution is not very robust though. If your IP address is 192.168.1.1, then the pattern above would also match 192.168.1.10 or 192.168.1.123. You can match a whole word with the angular brackets:

```
tshark -T fields -e ip.addr -E aggregator=" " | grep -vE "\<$(ip-ifconfig)\>"
tshark -T fields -e ip.addr -E aggregator=" " | sed "/\<$(ip-ifconfig)\>/d"
```

This should work most of the time. Note that the dot in the IP address should ideally be escaped, otherwise it will be used as the match-all character in the regular expression.

Finally, you could simply use the display filter in tshark:

```
tshark -T fields -e ip.addr -E aggregator=" " -Y "ip.addr != $(ip-ifconfig)"
```

This lets you build up quite complex filters.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for `tshark -l`.

```
 -l        Flush the standard output after the information for each packet is printed.  (This is not, strictly speaking, line-buffered if -V was specified; however, it is the same as line-
           buffered if -V wasn't specified, as only one line is printed for each packet, and, as -l is normally used when piping a live capture to a program or script, so that output for a
           packet shows up as soon as the packet is seen and dissected, it should work just as well as true line-buffering.  We do this as a workaround for a deficiency in the Microsoft
           Visual C++ C library.)

           This may be useful when piping the output of TShark to another program, as it means that the program to which the output is piped will see the dissected data for a packet as soon
           as TShark sees the packet and generates that output, rather than seeing it only when the standard output buffer containing that data fills up.
```